# Not able to update an entity in GAE project which is linked backend to an Android project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm new to Android and GAE and trying to create a sample app. I was able to achieve insertEntity and listEntity. All is working fine. But when I tried to update an entity using updateEntity, it just doen't work. The android project doesn't even call backend gae. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious thing here but not able to figure it out at all.

Here's my code of android app which calls update entity

```
private class ParentObjectUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<ParentObject, Void, UpdateParentObject> {

    /**
     * Calls appropriate CloudEndpoint to update
     *
     * @param params
     *            the object to update.
     */
    @Override
    protected UpdateParentObject doInBackground(ParentObject... params) {
        ParentObject parentObj = params[0];

        Parentobjectendpoint.Builder builder = new Parentobjectendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                null);

        builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);

        Parentobjectendpoint endpoint = builder.build();

        UpdateParentObject updatedObj;

        try {
            updatedObj = endpoint.updateParentObject(parentObj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            updatedObj = null;
        }

        return updatedObj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(UpdateParentObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

what about HttpRequestInitializer? Do I need to add PUT method here somehow?

Just to narrow down the scope, I'm working in local dev environment using Eclipse and nothing is deployed on GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `updatedObj = endpoint.updateParentObject(parentObj)` to `updatedObj = endpoint.updateParentObject(parentObj).execute();` to execute the Cloud Endpoint method.

Comment: Hi @user87049 .... I did what you said and it worked, but then I started getting another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546282/getting-null-pointer-exception-when-updating-a-entity-in-gae .... have you ever encountered this?